# Переключатель-ползунок On-Off: Как его понимать?

Tags: html, ui

Вот скажите, друзья, как понимать следующий переключатель:

[image: On-Off]

1. Переключатель показывает «On», значит переключатель включён; то есть чтобы его выключить, нужно перетянуть ползунок в обратную сторону.
2. Переключатель показывает «On», значит переключатель выключен, а «On» указывает на то, что чтобы его включить, нужно перетянуть на «On» ползунок.

Думаю, это не холиварный вопрос, так как такие переключатели всё чаще используют из-за их красоты, стало быть должно существовать чёткое понимание (ко мне оно, к сожалению, что-то не пришло).

Comment: Обычно подразумевается первый вариант, т.е. показывается текущее состояние. При выключенном же варианте, так же еще могут изменить и фон, например на серый.

Comment: Я думаю для UI также будет полезным использовать привычную гамму цветов, например, зеленый - вкл, красный - выкл. Или яркий цвет - признак вкл. состояния, более затемненный цвет - выкл. состояние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему опыту большинство пользователей (интуитивно оцениваю процентов 90) воспринимает "Да" как "Сейчас Да, если нажать - будет Нет", хотя вначале я сделал в проекте, подразумевая наооборот, потом сделали замечания и сделал так. По моему субъективному мнению, я бы вообще избегал такой элемент, а использовал бы что-то вроде радиобатона.

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как задать вопрос здесь, я также написал в техподдержку того сайта, откуда я его взял, чтобы услышать несколько мнений и на основе их сформировать ответ. Там мне ответили, что:

> Статус, отображаемый переключателем, соответствует позиции, в которой
>   находится опция. Таким образом, когда переключатель отображает статус
>   "On" как на приведенном Вами скриншоте, опция включена.